# jQuery doesn't let click on a link

Tags: jquery

I have a modal window (which is a confirmation box) where I have a link to the main page and it looks like this:

```
<div id="modal" href="#dialog">

<div id="boxes">
<div id="dialog" class="window">
Tu cuenta ha sido activada |
<a href="http://pasionesargentas.webatu.com" class="close"> Seguir</a>
</div>

<!-- Mask to cover the whole screen -->
<div id="mask"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

The scrip is this one:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//select all the a tag with name equal to modal
$('div[id=modal]').click(function(e) {

    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    //Get the A tag
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  
    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000); 
});

//if close button is clicked
$('.window a.close').click(function (e) {
         //Cancel the link behavior
    //e.preventDefault();   });

$('div[id=modal]').trigger('click');

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
//      $(this).hide();
//      $('.window').hide();
    });         
});
</script>
<!-- END of Dialog message | Pop up window -->
```

But when I click in 'Close window and go to home' I actually WANT to go to the href mentioned. I though that by removing the line *e.preventDefault();* it would go but I was wrong. Why is it preventing me to go to another page after I click on a link? It doesn't attempt to do anything :-/ but it works fine if I right click it and open the link on a new window/tab.
Any sugestions?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to capture the click event at all?

Comment: nope, but I tried to remove the whole function but still doesn't do any different.

Comment: Do any javascript errors show in the console? Also, if you're navigating to a new site, you need to put "http://" in front of the URL inside the href, otherwise it will look for a file called "home.com"

Comment: *confused* - First of all, a `div` with a `href` attribute is invalid HTML, hrefs must be attributed to anchor tags (`a`). Secondly, I don't understand what you try to achieve with that second function (`$('.window .close').click`). If you add `e.preventDefault();` it will cancel the link, so if you want the href to work as intended remove the second function. - Edit: @bfink is right, the URL home.com is kind of weird...

Comment: He said he removed the function though and it didn't make a difference....

Comment: @cbarg, can you post all of your javascript?

Comment: @bfink no errors on console. and I saved some letters to make it shorter.

Comment: Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/uDPz4/. You see that if the second function is neutralised, the link works as it should. This probably means that you have additional code in the first function that you haven't posted here which prevents the link to behave properly.

Comment: You don't close your `$('.window a.close').click(function (e) {` in the example you posted. Can you close that and try it?

Comment: The full code is posted now! @Tomm I think it has something to do with it but I don't know what. I'm actually removing the class out of the a tag. Probably the modal part is affecting ?

Answer (score 2):

Because `preventDefault()` does just that, prevents you from navigating away. If what you want to do is navigate away, then simply remove the call to `preventDefault()`.

Comment: removing preventDefault() or even the whole block doesn't work. (that's why I'm here :-)

Comment: Try adding the protocol to the "href" attribute on the anchor. "home.com" is not a valid url so maybe that's causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try:

1. `http://home.com`

   -- or --
2. `http://www.home.com`